# Sublime text 3: No output when building system

Tags: python, python-3.x, build, sublimetext, sublimetext3

So i cannot get my Python programs to run from Sublime text 3. When i try running the code nothing happens. All that happens is a small text saying

"Build finished" on the bottom.

This is what is in console

> Running python -u "C:\Users\Sindre\Documents\Python\Forbruk.py"

I have added python to windows path

The code:

```
def how_much (times_a_week, price):
'''
(int, int) -> str

Prints out my usage of that item.

>>> how_much (3, 25)
day: 10.71 kr
month: 326.11 kr
year: 3913.32 kr
lifetime: 309152 kr
hour: 0.44625000000000004 kr
minute: 0.0074375000000000005 kr
second: 0.00012395833333333334 kr
'''
day = round((times_a_week * price) / 7, 2)
month = round((times_a_week * price) * 4.34812141, 2)
year = round(month * 12, 2)
lifetime = round(year * 79)
hour = day / 24
minute = hour / 60
second = minute / 60

print("day:", day,"kr")
print("month:", month,"kr")
print("year:", year,"kr")
print("lifetime:", lifetime,"kr")
print("hour:", hour,"kr")
print("minute:", minute,"kr")
print("second:", second,"kr")
```

`how_much(3, 25)`

UPDATE

Found the problem. The problem was this line of code in my sublime settings `"show_panel_on_build": false`
Changed it to True and the it worked

Comment: what is in your Python script, and what is the expected output? What happens when you run your script from the command line?

Comment: does it run from the command line without errors? You may have lost the formatting copying and pasting, but there's no indentation in your code...

Answer (score 0):

Do you have:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':  
    main()
```

at the bottom? Replace main() with whatever function drives your script.

Comment: No... But what does that help?